# printing to usb printer in linux and tinker python code

Tags: printing

I need to know how to print in the printer not screen a tinker graphic. I created a tinker algorithm but then could not figure out how to print on the printer a copy of the tinker screen. I went looking for a tutorial or doc but can not find any thing I can understand or really makes sense. 
I suspect I need to make a file and then send it to my usb printer and get it to print. Where do I find that kind of information?

Comment: Do you mean `tkinter` instead of `tinker`?

Comment: Yeah your right! tkinter it is

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Tkinter *canvas* you can save the image to a file using the `.postscript` [method](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) on it.

Otherwise, you can always use various generic window or screen dumping tools such as the `import` command from ImageMagick to save a visible window, or your window manager's probable binding for the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key, perhaps in combination with <kbd>Control</kbd> or some other modifier.